# How to load Adobe Launch Tools after the User accepted cookie? (No Page Reload)

Tags: adobe, launch, adobe-analytics

I have enabled "UE Compliance" on Adobe Launch to avoid triggering any analytics if the user has not accepted the Cookie Terms.

As soon as the user accepts the terms, a cookie is set, but the Adobe Launch library did not properly load, and the page needs to be re-loaded in order to start tracking.

I want to start tracking right after the user accepted the cookie, without refreshing the page.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your code looks like that handles the terms/cookie setting, but ideally, you should trigger something for Launch to listen to, whenever the visitor accepts.

For example, whenever the visitor accepts the terms, add the following to your code at the appropriate place (e.g. the code that actually sets the cookie, if the cookie value is to allow)

`_satellite.track("pageview_gdpr_accepted");`

Then in Launch, create a rule of `Event Type` **Direct Call** :

[image]

Alternatively, you can create and broadcast a javascript [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), e.g.

```
var event = new Event("pageview_gdpr_accepted");
document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You should have this execute same as before (e.g. when the cookie with good value is set), and then in Launch, create a rule of `Event Type` **Custom Event**:

[image]

**Note:** If you go the **Custom Event** route, make sure you create/trigger on `document.body` or a decendant; Launch will not listen for custom events on `document` itself.

If you are unable to add code to your site to explicitly trigger A **Direct Call** or **Custom Event** rule, another alternative is to create a **Data Element** that references the `sat_track` cookie:

[image]

Then make a rule of `Event Type` **Data Element Change**:

[image]

with a condition to check if the **Data Element** value is true:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying @Crayon Violent
I understand your approach, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with what I am looking for. I have this set up: https://cloudup.com/cE72itwqJXm 
and when I load the page, the actual tools are not loading: https://cloudup.com/cKvhZBBJ9nn

I want to load the tools as soon as the user clicks on "Accept Cookie".

Comment: @carlosbvz the **Enable EU Compliance for Adobe Analytics** checkbox makes it to where Launch will look for the existence of `sat_track` cookie (unless you change the name in the config). If the cookie has a value "true" it will load AA. If it does not exist or has any other value, it will not. That is all this Launch feature does. It is up to you to implement something on your end that prompts the visitor to accept cookies, and to set the cookie itself. So, you will always get an error or notice about it on initial page load, because the visitor hasn't accepted anything yet.

Comment: Meanwhile, you have your own code that displays the notice and prompts visitor to accept, and sets the cookie to "true".  And from there, that is where my post comes in. You can't just pause loading of Launch while the visitor accepts. So you have to do something outlined in my post, _after_ the visitor accepts.

Comment: Well.. I suppose if you implemented the Launch Header script tag as async, you could instead output the Launch Header code when visitor accepts cookies, and then not have to worry about the EU Compliance config checkbox at all.

Comment: Yeah, what I was looking for was something like re-trying to load Launch after the user's cookie acceptance (even-though it failed on page load). 
I will asume there is not a natural way to do this, and either:

1- You take the hit of reloading the page when EU Compliance is checked (which is not optimum).
2- You forget about EU Compliance checkbox, and manually check for the cookie existence as a condition for the needed rules.

Comment: @carlosbvz Then I would suggest the last comment I made, where you use async version of Launch Header tag and only append it to DOM after cookie acceptance.

Comment: in case you need to reload Launch (cookie banner triggered from inside the Launch), just run `window.__satelliteLoaded = false;` and `window._satellite = null;` before you append new script element with src set to adobe launcher url (the same, like the first time)